# C# WPF DataStateBehaviour trigger either state when value is empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, label, string

I have an C#/WPF application where I use Label-Elements for some reason.
I can't use the TextBlock because of some designers intent. (I have tried changing them but the designer doesn't allow a change towards that Element)

Now I have to add a VisualStateGroup with 2 States.
State 1 should trigger when the Label.Content is an empty string.
State 2 should trigger when the Label.Content is anything else then an empty string.

I wanted to use a DataStateBehaviour for that but it doesn't seem to accept an empty string value.

How should I proceed? How can I get my States to trigger on a label with an empty string (or not)?

Comment: First thought is to use a value converter within your XAML to return a bool result regarding the string being empty or not.

Comment: A value converter is a good one. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: I will now propose that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a value converter within your XAML to return a bool result regarding the string being empty or not.